# Should we cancel the fortnightly chat session in the Physics chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

In the early days of the Physics SE we struggled to get people interested in using our chat room [The h Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). One of the tactics we used was to [schedule a one hour chat session](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-h-bar?tab=schedule) once every two weeks, and this worked pretty well. However the chat room has become a lot more lively over the years since then, and this scheduled chat session is now largely ignored. The only time I notice it is when I have to field yet another question from a new member asking what it is.

So my question for the panel is should we cancel it?

Comment: I'm so glad that it was John Rennie who composed this Meta question, because otherwise we would have missed out on a chance to use "fortnightly."

Comment: How about accepting the answer now that the event has been removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think we should cancel it.

I've been pretty active in chat for the last several months, and I haven't once seen the chat session used as a special event.  If anything, it usually falls on a time when things are pretty quiet.

I haven't seen it brought up in meta for several years.  Any important discussion seems to flow pretty well in comments on meta threads (and chats stemming off of that if necessary).  There doesn't seem to be much need to promote the chat, and I would even say the weekly promotion doesn't seem to actually bring us active users.  I've also seen it lead to more confusion than anything else.

So, to get back to my original opinion, since it doesn't have much use and can confuse people, I think we should cancel it.

Comment: Makes sense to me. On a personal note, the chat sessions are now at a pretty inconvenient time for me and I haven't been able to attend for the past few years. So even though I used to be a strong proponent of the chat sessions, these days I don't personally have any incentive to keep them going.